# Symfony 1.4, form based on model, I dont need some widgets

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

In Symfony 1.4 Im using a form based on model. But there are some widgets/fields I must need to validate. I couldnt find `removeWidget()` or something like that, how to remove some fields not to be checked/validated?

EDIT: baseForm

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'f1'          => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
  'f2'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
  'f3'    => sfWidgetFormInputText()
));

$this->setValidators(array(
  'f1'          => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('ID')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('ID'), 'required' => false)),
  'f2'  => new sfValidatorInteger(),
  'f3'    => new sfValidatorInteger()
));
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('task[%s]');
$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
$this->setupInheritance();
parent::setup();
```

and now somehow I must edit the `configure()` method so that validator wont check 'f1' field.

Comment: We definitely need to see your form class and your template that renders the form. Not the whole thing.. Just the relevant bits.

Comment: Show us the whole code: the action, the custom form, etc ... not the base one..

Comment: well, in the template, the form is rendered customly: <?php echo $form['field']->renderRow(); ?> in the action I simply create: $this->form = new TaskForm(); and bind: $this->form->bind ($request->getParameter('task'));

Comment: Then what do you have inside your `TaskForm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply unset the widget from the form

```
class XYZForm extends BaseXYZForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
       //....
       unset($this['unwanted_widget']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need edit BaseForm class.

You can make:

```
 $this->validatorSchema['widget_name'] = new sfValidatorPass();
```

Or for example, each of widget have option **"required"**

String widget:

```
$this->validatorSchema['widget_name'] = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false));
```